# I absolutely cannot factory rest my Huawei H881C tracfone

Tags: factory-reset

Every function on my Huawei H881C tracfone have "unfortunately stopped". I've tried many times to factory reset my phone but it WILL NOT do it. Please help i'm out of options!

Answer (score 1):

## **Factory reset H881C**

***warning everything will be erased***

1. Remove battery for a minute, then re-insert
2. Simultaneously press **POWER** and **VOLUME UP** until it vibrates
3. Release the **POWER** when Huawei logo shows
4. Release the **VOLUME UP** when Android logo shows up
5. Select **WIPE/FACTORY RESET** when blue menu shows up
6. Select **REBOOT SYSYTEM**

after rebooting, your phone will start up.